Install drivers for Arduino IDE
I am a Windows user and recently shifted to Ubuntu. I have installed Arduino IDE before on Windows 11 by following the tutorial, but after this shift, I am unable to install the same software. It's urgent, and the issue is similar to this post.
Arduino driver problem
My code and all other things are working fine with the Arduino UNO board. I installed the boards in IDE and am now trying to use the DEV KIT V board for ESP32. The issue is that it says "No serial data received" error. The same code is running fine on Arduino UNO. What may be the issue? My friend told me it was the driver issue, but how is it possible that some drivers are working fine with Arduino UNO but not with ESP32? The same board works fine with Windows Arduino IDE.

Check the product images compared to your board and look to see if there is a jumper applied to the jumper pins in the product images. If so, and if there is no jumper applied to your board or if different, then apply a jumper as seen in the product images and try again.

how is it possible that some drivers are working fine with Arduino UNO but not with ESP32? ... is this really the question you want to ask? ... the answer does not tell you how to solve the problem

thanks for the replies. Yes, I was also curious about this issue and worked on it. I was missing some important code so I corrected it. Some of the problem is solved but I still need help.
